# Posting time to .NET api 2 controller changes to time + GMT offset

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, timezone

I have an angularJS application that does some basic calendar functions. After edits, when I post the time back to the server I notice that the time is not what the user entered, but rather the user entered time plus the GMT offset.

For example if I write the Calendar Event to console.log right before the post I see

```
end: Thu May 15 2014 11:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
id: 32525
start: Thu May 15 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Here is my method in angularJS that saves the Event

```
saveEvent = function(calEvent){
    console.log(calEvnt);
    $http.post('http://localhost:52491/api/SimpleCalendarEvent/', calEvnt);
}
```

But a break point on the post method of the api controller shows

```
start = May 25 2014, 3:00 PM
end = May 15 2014, 4:30 pm
```

Here is my post method on the api controller

```
public void Post(jsCalendarEvent calEvent)
{
    //calEvent.start = calEvent.start.ToLocalTime();
    //calEvent.end = calEvent.end.ToLocalTime(); 
    SaveJsCalendarEvent cmd = new SaveJsCalendarEvent(_context);
    cmd.Event = calEvent;
    cmd.Execute();
}
```

and here is jsCalendar Event

```
public class jsCalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}
```

If I uncomment

```
calEvent.start = calEvent.start.ToLocalTime();
calEvent.end = calEvent.end.ToLocalTime();
```

everything is correct, but this is a disaster just waiting to happen. I was someone has ran across this an knows of a better way to fix this.

Comment: How are you posting time to/from the server?

Comment: @Dai - just using $http.post()

Comment: We need more code, to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: `ToLocalTime` will use the time zone of the *server*, which is almost never appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose without more detail, but you might consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` in your `jsCalendarEvent` class.